# Query multiple 'where' clauses

Tags: query

How do you write a query that allows for multiple WHERE clauses?

This is a valid query

```
SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, IsClosed
FROM Case 
WHERE IsClosed = false
```

This is not a valid query

```
SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, IsClosed
FROM Case 
WHERE IsClosed = false IsDeleted = false
```

This is also not a valid query

```
SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, IsClosed
FROM Case 
WHERE IsClosed = false, IsDeleted = false
```

The resource I am using is here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index.htm

Comment: Simply use the keywords `AND` and `OR`: `SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, IsClosed
FROM Case 
WHERE IsClosed = false AND IsDeleted = false`

Comment: @Lex Ahh, why didn't I think of that. Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @Lex, why not re-write your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted and you can get reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the keywords `AND` and `OR`. Like this: `SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, IsClosed FROM Case WHERE IsClosed = false AND IsDeleted = false`. Keep in mind that `AND` binds stronger than `OR`, like multiplication binds stronger than summation. So if you're gonna mix them up, be sure to put parantheses around the terms.